# Can't cope with running Spring: trouble with candidate component class for jdbc

Tags: spring

I have set a task for myself. So far it is just to start Spring.

Repository: https://github.com/Kifsif/reusable
Trace back:  https://dpaste.com/CA9YZ4Q3M

The error seems to be localized in the phrase "candidate component class" for jdbc. But I don't seem to have mentioned any database so far. And I'm making my project's structure along the lines of pom.xml generated by Spring Boot initializr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is warning in output log:

```
** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.
```

Your `MainApplication.java` is in the default package (`src/main/java/MainApplication`).

Please create a new package (for example: `scr/main/java/example` and move your `MainApplication` into that package, then it works.